# Useless expression when removing 'return' keyword from conditional

Tags: scala

SonarQube has just evaluated the following expression as a code smell due to `return` keyword being present in method body. However, if I remove the `return` IntelliJ will warn about an expression which is useless.

The conditional is the following.

```
 if (map.contains("numProperties")) {
    if (map("numProperties").toInt >= 20)
      return true

    return false
  }
  true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
map.get("numProperties").forall(_.toInt >= 20)
```

The `get` returns an `Option`, and calling `forall` on an `Option` returns `true` if the `Option` is empty or if the test on the contents returns `true`.

Keeping the original form it would be:

```
if (map.contains("numProperties")) {
  if (map("numProperties").toInt >= 20) {
    true
  } else {
    false
  }
} else {
 true
}
```